# Antd select - always shows placeholders for multi select component while multiple tags are selected

Tags: antd

I want to always show a placeholder text in the Select component, specifically when multiple tags are selected (or at least 1).

Returning `null` from `tagRender` does half of what I need but then the input is just clear. I need the placeholder to persist.

Is this possible?

```
const selectOptions = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  const value = i.toString(36) + i;
  selectOptions.push({ label: value, value });
}

const SelectDemo = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (selected) => {
    setSelected(selected);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      value={selected}
      tagRender={() => null}
      options={selectOptions}
      mode="multiple"
      size="default"
      placeholder="Please select"
      onChange={handleChange}
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
    />
  );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bhabha-rx8xt5?file=/index.js:75-125)

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1: Leveraging Select Props

You can achieve customization using specific Select properties such as maxTagCount, maxTagPlaceholder, and tagRender. Here's an example:

```
<Select
  showArrow
  mode="multiple"
  placeholder="Select"
  options={options}
  maxTagCount={1}
  maxTagPlaceholder={(omittedValues) => <Badge>{omittedValues.length + 1}</Badge>}
  tagRender={() => <p>Placeholder</p>}
/>
```

By combining these props, you can control the display of tags or even completely remove the tags from the Select Field and achieve your desired customization in a more straightforward manner.
For more info, checkout the [antd docs](https://ant.design/components/select#select-props).

### Method 2: Utilizing `dropdownRender`

You can use the dropdownRender property. However, it's crucial not to render the Ant Design menu within this function, as it may interfere with the rendering of tags. Here's an example:

```
<Select
  // Other Select props...
  dropdownRender={(menu) => (
    <>
      {menu}
      <Divider style={{ margin: '8px 0' }} />
      <Space style={{ padding: '0 8px 4px' }}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Please enter item"
          ref={inputRef}
          value={name}
          onChange={onNameChange}
          onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        />
        <Button type="text" icon={<PlusOutlined />} onClick={addItem}>
          Add item
        </Button>
      </Space>
    </>
  )}
/>

In this example, avoid rendering {menu} to ensure Ant Design doesn't interfere with tag rendering. However, note that this approach requires implementing a custom dropdown menu.
```